# Subsequences and blocks of Schauder bases

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $(e_n)$ and $(f_n)$ are both Schauder bases of $X$.

1. Does there exist a proper closed subspace $Y\subset X$, and appropriate **subsequences** of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ that are bases for $Y$?
2. Does there exist a proper closed subspace $Y\subset X$, and appropriate **block subsequences** of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ that are bases for $Y$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi My thoughts are that both questions probably  have a negative answer.

Comment: You can peturb the standard unit vector basis $(e_n)$ of $\ell_1$ to obtain a basis $(f_n)$ of $\ell_1$ in such a way that each $f_j$ has full support. If $Y$ contains an $f_j$ and if a subsequence of $(e_n)$ is a basis of $Y$, then $Y$ would have to contain every $e_j$.

Comment: @DavidMitra This answers 1, do you have an argument for 2 as well? If you write it as answer I will accept.